# Laravel redirect route from get to resources

Tags: laravel, routes

i'm trying to redirect this action method in my controller but i couldn't make it work. the action will goes to **posts Resources @show**

**here is the controller.**

```
 public function readbyid(Request $request){


   if(isset($request->data['id'])){
    return redirect()->action(
        'PostController@show', ['id' => $request->data['id']]
    );
}else{
    return redirect()->back();
}


}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('markread/{id}', 'NotifyController@readbyid' );
```

Comment: because you are passing `id` replace with other name

Comment: which id ur talking about?

Comment: is both `id` from route and in controller are same ?

Comment: yes , but the PostController 'id' is diffrent

Comment: why you used `if(isset($request->data['id'])){` this ?

Comment: What should be the proper term?

Comment: if `data['id']` is not referring `'markread/{id}'` this `id` then change its name

Comment: data['id'] and 'markread/{id}' is same

Comment: then im trying to go to this controller 'PostController@show', ['id'

Answer (score 0):

For optional parameters, use '?'

`Route::get('markread/{id?}', 'NotifyController@readbyid');`

Comment: if i use this code i can go to certain post id  return redirect()->action(
        'PostController@show', ['id' => 26]
    );

Answer (score 0):

Use `$request->id` instead `$request->data['id']`

you are not getting any value `$request->data['id']` like this thats why it goes to the else part.